# Display the value of plotband border in the highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Are there ways to display the values of plotband border in the highcharts?

In the highcharts, there are two plotbands, the fisrt is from 60 to 90, and the second is from 90 to 140, as following picture:

[Example picure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5XJs.png)

And the plotband code snippet is following:

```
......
plotBands: [{
  from: 60,
  to: 90,
  color: 'rgba(245, 245, 235, 1)'
}, {
  from: 90,
  to: 140,
  color: 'rgba(230, 238, 239, 1)'
}]
......
```

I want to display 60, 90 and 140 on the right to let user know the range of plotbands.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`plotBands.label`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands.label) like this:

```
plotBands: [{
  color: 'yellow',
  from: 80,
  to: 110,
  label: {
    text: '80-110',  //the text shown on the chart
    align: 'right',
    x: 65,
    style: {
      color: 'yellow', //color of the text
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }        
  }
}]
```

Where you can replace the text with whatever you may like. This works best if you either have the label on the plot area, or create a margin and have the label outside the plot area.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ljgh907p/8/